# Getting table, order by most liked values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm using MySQL. I have a table named 'words'

[image]

If a user enter a new value 'the word_liked_id' will be 0.
If a user likes a value, it will copy the row of the value, and add to 'word_liked_Id' the id of liked value.

My question is, how I write a query which show me the table of regular values (word_liked_id == 0), order by the most liked rows first?

I only know basic MySql, I don't know how to create this "loop needed" action so I don't have a query to share. Thanks for any assistance.

Example of desired output:
For example I have 3 rows which the 'word_liked_id' is 93, which means the value in id 93 has 3 likes.
I have another 2 rows which the 'word_liked_id' is 45, which means the value in id 45 has 2 likes.

I want to show the table order by the values with the most likes.

Output:
So the output will be:
row 1: everything in id 93, (Which has the most likes of 3)
row 2: everything in id 45, (Which has the second most likes of 2)
row 3: others with less or none likes.

Comment: @RiggsFolly no, I need to show the table based on the order of the rows with the most likes. A row can be liked by multi users, so there can be multi likes to the same row. I need to count each row how many likes it has, and somehow make the table order by the rows with the most likes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation and a `join`:

```
select w.*, wl.num_likes 
from words w join
     (select wl.word_liked_id, count(*) as num_likes
      from words wl
      group by wl.word_liked_id
     ) wl
     on wl.word_liked_id = w.id
order by wl.num_likes desc;
```

If you want all rows, even those with no likes, then use `left join` instead of `join`.

Comment: By the way, if I want it to do it only where words have a specific letter, LIKE '%א%'. Where do I add this WHERE\LIKE check in the query?

Comment: @Naveh . . . You can add a `where` clause before the `order by`.

Comment: AH I tried it before, was thinking I'm doing it not correctly. I tried again and it worked, just if I try to get only values which word_liked_id = 0, I get the error: "Column 'word_liked_id' in where clause is ambiguous". But I've manage to get the values I want anyway in a different approch so everything is fine, if I'll get in trouble I'll open a new question. Thanks a lot anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions.
[Window Functions in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html)

MySQL supports window functions that, for each row from a query, perform a calculation using rows related to that row.

In your case you can use the RANK() or DENSE_RANK() functions.
See: [RANK](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_rank)